# How do i update live content on Nancy Hosting Framework

Tags: c#, nancy

Iam using Nancy Framework with C# and my views are rendered from HTML files. If i need to udate the code in my HTML,CSS or JS (which is part of the content), I have to go through the long annoying process of

1. Stopping the running C# project
2. Editing my HTML,CSS or JS File
3. Saving the changes
4. Running the C# project
5. Refreshing the browser
6. Waiting for the connection to localhost:8080 to be established (This usually takes a bit longer on the first run and that is even more annoying)
   7.Finally i get to see if that CSS styling has been applied...if it has not be applied, i have to start the whole process from **1.**

Please help me if u have a better way of doing this if not maybe just explain to me why i always have to wait a few more seconds for the first run of the C# project to start allowing connections on the browser.

Comment: Settings things up with Nancy such that you only have to reload in the browser to see HTML/JS/CSS changes is entirely possible and normal. So I think we something more to go on here. What do you use for hosting? Have you set any conventions up?

Comment: @ChristianHorsdal iam simply running my c# app and then requests start being accepted.....Iam new to nancy but my code is a folk of this github project https://github.com/richorama/Jukebox

Comment: Learn patience, young grasshopper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nancy does not cache CSS or JS files, they are pass-through files when they exist under Content folder, or if you explicitly set them up in the static conventions.

To disable View Caching, simply disable caches in your bootstrapper:

`StaticConfiguration.DisableCaches = true`

**Edit:**

Based on your comment:

https://github.com/richorama/Jukebox/blob/master/Jukebox/Controllers/Home.cs#L11

```
namespace Jukebox.Controllers
{
    public class Home : NancyModule
    {
        public Home()
        {
            Get["/"] = x =>
            {
                return Response.AsFile("default.htm");
            };
        }    
    }
}
```

This will load the htm file off the disk every request. So I'm not entirely sure what issues you're running into. None-the-less try disabling the caches.

Also caching is only enabled when you're running the code in Release mode...

**Edit 2:**

Since you're using a console app and files are copied to the bin.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-root-path#changing-the-root-path

Create a implementation of the rootpath provider pointing to your dev directory. Configure it to only run during development.

Comment: Every time i run the C# app, New Copies of the content and default.htm files are made in the Debug/bin folder. As a result if i make changes in the ide (in running mode), these changes are not applied to the files in the Debug/bin folder UNTIL i stop the IDE and re-run the C# Application. Only then will the IDE recopy new versions on the content files and the default.htm file into the Debug\bin folder. Responses seem to be made from the Debug/Bin folder during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get `304 - Not Modified` HTTP status code for the HTML, JS and CSS files? If so, then the files are cached by browser. Disable the caching either on the server side as Phill suggested or disable the browser caching (which might be counter-productive).